# No platforms after Add platform cordova

Tags: cordova

Sience last week I'm trying to get cordova working and no luck yet.
Step by step from this doc: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

After cordova platform add android command I get no errors. Last response "Creating android project..."

And then I'm trying cordova build command and I get error:
No platforms added to this project. Please use 'cordova platform add '

What am I doing wrong???!!!

Comment: can you mention your commands step by step.

Comment: npm install -g cordova <enter> cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld <enter> cd hello <enter> chcp 65001 (issue with "Ł" letter in path fro ant) <enter> cordova platform add android <enter> cordova build <enter>

Comment: i have tried with your commands but i can successfully build it. have you tried sudo before npm install -g cordova.

Comment: Can you try phonegap build android or cordova build android

Comment: phonegap build android: Error: write EIO at...

Comment: For me it worked with `phonegap local build android`. The new phonegap is quite cool, but it's so poorly documented that it's really frustrating to get started

Comment: You can add `-d` to any cordova command to enter "debug" mode - the commands should spit out more information this way and you might see the error. Maybe try this. Also, are you online and connected to the internet when you do `cordova platform add android`?  Have you correctly set up npm?

Answer (score 1):

Please try removing the android platform and adding it back right away:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky getting this working, especially for Android.  I ran into several problems, so make sure you have done everything below:

## Pre-requisites

- Node installed (should place it in the PATH)
- JDK installed (and \bin in PATH)
- ANT installed (and \bin in PATH)
- Android/Eclipse SDK (and Android\sdk\tools directory in PATH)
- PhoneGap installed (via Node)
- Pre-requisites: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/348446/trainings/android.html

Comment: I can install phonegap 2.9.0 without command lines.... I wanted to ude newset version 3.2

Answer (score 0):

check your config.xml syntax. a not closing tag caused this issue for me.