# Error to add platform in cordova project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have install cordova but i'm facing the problem to add android platforms.

All the steps is going very well but when I'm trying to add platform command

```
"cordova platform add android"
```

cli screen show me

```
 "adding android project..."
```

& than nothing happen..

[image]

In the project directory platform folder is created but it is empty..

Please help me to solve the problem.

Installed system versions are as follows,

```
 1.cordova version 6.2.0
 2.node version 4.4.1
 3.install sdk api 23
 4.install jdk
```

Comment: are you working in ionic or cordova in which you are work and trying to add android

Comment: please check to here http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2015/03/hybrid-mobile-apps-with-ionic-framework.html

Comment: check the your environment variable for android paths

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569929/ionic-installing-error-in-windows-7

Comment: this https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-windows.html helped me a lot with cordova.

Comment: are you got the solution ?

Comment: no dear anyone can please come on team-viewer to solve my problem? i would be very thankful to you for the act of this kindness

Comment: @ArsalanArain Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471182/no-platforms-after-add-platform-cordova Would be glad to help. Buzz me when online

Comment: every thing is well please come on teamviewer to solve my problem.

Comment: @Gandhi Please Suggest me any solution.

Comment: @Arsalan can we checkout on team viewer tomorrow (may 30) 10.30 AM IST as its Sunday today?

Comment: first of all thanks for your reply.. please get in touch with me i'll arrange my time i will contact to you as soon as possible.. thank you so much.

Comment: @Gandhi ok i'm free please arrange time for remote desktop.

Comment: @ArsalanArain you gotta share team viewer credentials

Comment: @Gandhi not here but i email you please send me your email.

Comment: @Gandhi Please Check.

Comment: @ArsalanArain i have incomaptible version with yours. Reinstalling teamviewer

Comment: @Gandhi Got it i'm waiting.

Comment: @ArsalanArain Connection lost. you are not reachable. There??

Comment: @Gandhi please wait.

Comment: @ArsalanArain I retried connecting. No luck. But it may work this time.

Comment: @Arsalan worked finally?

Comment: @Gandhi i tried but again it showing me the same error. please comeback again on teamviewer..

Comment: @ArsalanArain Are you there? In your case even, browser platform is also not getting added. I guess you may have to reinstall nodejs as well and try

Comment: @Gandhi ok getting touch with me i am reinstalling

Comment: @ArsalanArain do you want me to login?

Comment: @Gandhi tum skype ya facebook pr ho ?

Comment: @ArsalanArain we can connect on team viewer if you want

Comment: @Gandhi problem solve i use adobe build online cloud for build apk there are no need to worry about environment just upload the zip file and you job is done :-D

Comment: @Arsalan cool.. But we could have resolved locally I feel

Comment: @ArsalanArain i dint get what you mean?