# IONIC: Error: No platforms added to this project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have successfully executed  following command as shown on this [website](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/):

```
$ npm install -g cordova ionic
$ ioniv -v && cordova -v
$ ionic start fitnessApp blank
$ cd fitnessApp
$ ionic platform add android
```

**but getting error when i try to execute command:**

```
$ ionic build android
```

ERRORS:
[image]

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Actually as per you error screen shot, the issue is with adding android platform. The build error is the consequence of add platform error. Try adding browser platform, it may fail too. We are dealing with the same problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37451465/error-to-add-platform-in-cordova-project which is yet to be figured out. Try out the suggestions and keep us posted

Comment: Hello Ashu, It as a PATH problem.

Comment: yes it's path problem you didn't add android sdk path in your environment variable... please download latest android sdk and give path in environment variable and try again..

Comment: @Naitik how to add android SDK to path and where can i find SDK?

Comment: @Ashu do follow https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_HowTo.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - ionic - no platforms added to this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829827/android-ionic-no-platforms-added-to-this-project)