# cordova platform add android doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, platform

I'm trying to create my first App, but now I have this problem :

[image]

When adding a new platform by `cordova platform add android`
It only shows `Adding android project...`

And it does nothing more. 
The folder platforms is empty and it did not create the folder android. 
Please help.

[UPDATE]

Add -d to command and get this

```
C:\hello>cordova platform add android -d  
No scripts found for hook "before_platform_add". 
No version supplied. 
Retrieving version from config.xml... 
Adding android project...
```

( Sorry for my english ! )

Comment: Check this if it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471182/no-platforms-after-add-platform-cordova

Comment: love u, i ad -d to command and get this 
C:\hello>cordova platform add android -d
No scripts found for hook "before_platform_add".
No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
Adding android project...

Comment: Can you try to run `cordova requirements` and see what happens?

Comment: Error: CordovaError: No platforms added to this project. Please use `cordova pla
tform add <platform>`.

Comment: C:\hello>cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:

Available platforms:
  amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
  android ~5.1.1
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0
  browser ~4.1.0
  firefoxos ~3.6.3
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~4.3.1
  wp8 ~3.8.2 (deprecated)

Comment: What does `cordova requirements` return?

Comment: This >>
Error: CordovaError: No platforms added to this project. Please use cordova platform add <platform>.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see that a while ago. How about `cordova info`?

Comment: Collecting Data...


Node version: v4.4.6

Cordova version: 6.2.0

Config.xml file:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widge
ts" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready eve
nt.

Comment: </description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
Apache Cordova Team

Comment: Is to long to type here :/

Comment: You can always edit your question and update it accordingly so other people can also help. can you try the basic `cordova platform add browser`? Sorry for the numerous trials, I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the given information

Comment: Thats works ! create a browser folder... what do you think i have somthing worng with path for android or something like that?
Dont say sorry ! thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. Check your paths for java and android sdk if it's correct.

Comment: In Path have this 
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\apache-ant;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
And the homes 
ANDROID_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Comment: Try adding a specific android version by `cordova platform add android@5.1.1`

Comment: Nope =( 
C:\hello>cordova platform add android@5.1.1 -d
No scripts found for hook "before_platform_add".
Adding android project...

Now no have the "No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml... "

Answer (score 0):

1. Path Confirmation

Can you try to go over your path and check if the paths are correct?

Especially since some are in (x86) and some are not.

Also, instead of `C:\apache-ant` try `C:\apache-ant\bin`.

Even though `cordova is already installed, add`npm` in your path as well just to be sure.

Check in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\` because your commands might be inside this.

Add `ANT_HOME` -  `C:\apache-ant` to your variables. It might make a difference.

2. Confirm paths

`java -version`

`javac -version`

`node -v`

`cordova -v`

`npm -v`

`android` (if it pops up)

3. Try to start over

`cordova platform remove android --verbose`

`cordova platform add android --verbose`

If still fails, remove and add `cordova` again.

Comment: i can create firefoxos, browser but android no.... 
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)

C:\>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_91

C:\>node -v
v4.4.6

C:\>cordova -v
6.2.0

C:\>npm -v
3.10.3

C:\>android

c:\>
(Android Pops up ) 
Still no adding the folder to platforms i really shocked with this i format the pc for try again buy still not working...

Comment: Have you tried running `create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld` exactly from the tutorial? and adding the `bin` folder of `ant` as well to the path?

Comment: Yup exactly from the tutorial, and yes %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\android-sdk\tools;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\apache-ant\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\HMSurbit\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;
( I change patch of android to try avoid <program files x86> )

Comment: Try this: `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\apache-ant\b‌​in;C:\Users\HMSurbit\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\android-sdk\tools` without a semicolon in the end. Also, check your `CompSpec` variable in your environment variables and remove the semicolon at the end if present.

Comment: Man many thanks for your help, is all ok now. I download a version 4.1.1 and 5.0.0 and try to add platafor with "add android@5.1.1" and works! but still not working only with "add android " i dont know why but i dont need more information. 
MANY MANY THANKS MAN !