# Cordova gives "Adding android project.." on 'cordova platform add android' but when 'cordova build android' is run it gives "No Platform is added"

Tags: android, cordova

On `cordova platform add android`

Cordova gives "`Adding android project..`"

But when `cordova build android` error is next run

it gives `No Platform is added` error

[The image shows the steps I am following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoTil.png)

Additional Info

```
node --version v4.4.5
cordova --version 6.2.0
javac -version 1.8.0_92
ant -version Apache Ant<TM> version 1.9.7
adb version Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36
            Revision fd9e4d07b0f5-android
```

I have also set the following

a. path variable

```
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;C:\Users\Nikhil\ant\bin;C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

b. ANT_HOME

```
C:\Users\Nikhil\ant
```

c. JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
```

d. ANDROID_HOME

```
C:\Users\Nikhil\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Android 6.0 (API 23) is installed in  Android SDK.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous people have had similar problem.

Please try to add a specific android version by

`cordova platform add android@5.0.0`

You can try other versions by referring to the main documentation, but make sure to remove any previous versions prior to adding another android version.

[Android Platform Guide - Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
cordova platform add android --save
```

then after run: `cordova platform ls`

check the folder platforms for an android folder.
and your config.xml that its stored.

Comment: try running it with -d to get more info. cordova -d platform add android

Comment: No script found for hook "before_platform_add". No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml.  Adding android project...  This is what I am getting now.

Comment: try running a cordova platform rm android and then add it again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111715/cordova-platform-add-android-doesnt-work